# where does docker upload server.py file?

Tags: api, rest, docker

Setting: lots of mp3 records of customer support conversations somewhere in a db. Each mp3 record has 2 channels, one is customer rep, another is customer's voice.

I need to extract embedding(tensor) of a customer's voice. It's a 3 step process:
get the channel, cut 10 secs, convert to embedding. I have all 3 functions for each step.

embedding is a vector tensor:

```
"tensor([[0.6540e+00, 0.8760e+00, 0.898e+00, 
    0.8789e+00, 0.1000e+00, 5.3733e+00]])
```

Tested with postman. Get embedding function:

[image: k]

I want to build a rest api that connects on 1 endpoint to the db of mp3 files and outputs embedding to another db.

I need to clarify important feature about docker.

When i run "python server.py" flask makes it available on my local pc - 127.0.1.01/9090:

```
def get_embedding(file):
    #some code

@app.route('/health')
def check():
     return jsonify({'response':'OK!'})

@app.route('/get_embedding')
def show_embedding():
    return get_embedding(file1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=9090)
```

when i do it with docker - where goes the server and files? where does it become available online, can docker upload all the files to default docker cloud?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a Dockerfile to build your Docker image and after that, Run a `container` from that image exposing on the port and then you can access it `machineIP:PORT`

Below is the example
**Dockerfile**

```
#FROM tells Docker which image you base your image on (in the example, Python 3).
FROM python:3

#WORKDIR tells which directory container has to word
WORKDIR /usr/app

# COPY files from your host to the image working directory
COPY my_script.py .

#RUN tells Docker which additional commands to execute.
RUN pip install pystrich

CMD [ "python", "./my_script.py" ]
```

> Ref:- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

And then build the image,
`docker build -t server .`

> Ref:- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Once, Image is built start a container and expose the port through which you can access your application.
E.g.

```
docker run -p 9090:9090 server
```

`-p`  Publish a container's port(s) to the host

And access your application on `localhost:9090` or `127.0.0.1:9090` or `machineIP:ExposePort`

Comment: @nichasay thx u, but my question is more about.. how does another person get access to my web service ? cuz if i turn my computer off, the server is gone

Comment: For that host, the service on Cloud, either on AWS or Azure or GCP